# Removing all "/node/$id" urls from xml sitemap plugin

Tags: xml-sitemap

In my project pages are implemented using [Panels](https://drupal.org/project/panels) module and contain lot of nodes.

I've set up xml sitemap module, generated xml, and currently i can see many "/node/$id" urls, but:

1. That are not actual pages themselves, but parts of pages (or even parts of menus, etc)
2. Pages have aliases, that should be used, but not "/node/$id" urls.

How it is possible to remove "/node/$id" urls from sitemap and leave just pages with aliases?

Comment: You need to go through all the nodes you _don't_ want in the sitemap, and exclude them manually.

Comment: Using the [Content Access](https://drupal.org/project/content_access) module can stop people from accessing certain content types, but I'm not sure if that will remove them from your xml site map or not. Maybe try it...

Comment: Which XML Sitemap submodules are you using?  Node?  Menu?

Answer (score 0):

To implement this with pages, implemented with Panels, it is necessary to manage pages urls manually with Xml Sitemap Custom subplugin: https://drupal.org/node/1235804